# Need to filter a column every X rows

Tags: r, filter

I have a column with dates, and I want to filter every X rows.

```
df <- read.table(text = 'date
01-02-2010  
02-02-2010  
03-02-2010  
07-02-2010  
08-02-2010  
09-02-2010
10-02-2010
11-02-2010  
12-02-2010  
13-02-2010
14-02-2010 ', header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

iris |> 
  mutate(row = row_number()) |> 
  filter(row %% 3 == 0) # Change the value 3 to whatever you are looking for.
```